# Trying to use repo-sync to sync too lineage OS repository, get fetch errors, tried force-sync

Tags: android, linux

I've tried too run it multiple times, I've used --force-sync, various amounts of threads, and it always breaks on this part:

```
Fetching projects: 100% (639/639)  
error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

I am using the most up to date version of debian, and would prefer not to switch over to Ubuntu if possible.

Comment: Actual command I used: repo sync -j1 -f --force-sync

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*